# How to create an AWS Ubuntu 12.04 x64 AMI from scratch?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ami

How do I create a Ubuntu 12.04 AMI?

I would like to create a private AMI to host Brenda (https://github.com/jamesyonan/brenda). There are public AMIs that exist for Brenda -- which I've successfully used -- but now I want to create my own private AMI.

According to the Readme.md file, the first step says to "use the Ubuntu 12.04 x64 AMI as a starting point". I'm new to AWS, and am having difficulty locating a Ubuntu 12.04 AMI. The AMIs that Amazon provides are, from what I can tell, Red Hat. I see Ubuntu AMIs on Amazon Marketplace, but I'm overwhelmed with how many options there are, and my gut says that I shouldn't have to pay to get a base Ubuntu image.

I suspect that there's something obvious or easy that I'm missing, as I've done lots of searching online and can't find an answer. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Full list of (current) Ubuntu AMIs are located are [listed on Ubuntu's site](https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/locator/ec2/). Many things on the AWS Marketplace don't actually cost money, but third-party AMIs are all put onto the Marketplace. If you're trying to build a custom AMI, I'd suggest looking at [Packer](https://www.packer.io/).

Comment: Not sure how you are searching that you are only finding Red Hat AMIs. Amazon provides much more than just Red Hat. When I launch an instance via the AWS console the first thing I see is a list of AMIs which include Amazon Linux, Red Hat, SUSE LInux, **Ubuntu** and Windows Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to answer this for the console. There are many other ways you could do this.

Go to the EC2 console and click on launch instance. On the left you will see AMI options. Quickstart is highlighted by default. Click on Community AMIs. Then, you should see a search box on the right. Type in the word Precise. Precise Pangolin is the name of the ubuntu 12 release. Hit enter, you should see all 12.04 releases. Pick anyone you like. These should all be free - as in charge you only for EC2 hours. Only market place solutions could cost more than what you need for EC2. Hope this helps, somewhat.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the Ubuntu images are listed on AWS Marketplace, but the software cost is $0.00/hr (you can select a more expensive option with a support plan). What's the problem with [this](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B007Z5YWX4) AMI?